# Incorrect values of NDSI index after TOA correction

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, landsat, ndvi, landsat-8

I would like to calculate NDSI index (Normalized-Difference Snow Index) which basically is the same as NDVI but presents snow not vegetation :). As in NDVI the range of values for NDSI should be <-1, 1>. However, after application TOA correction values of NDSI extend range <-1,1> and it's difficult to find treshold for snow because most of the NDSI values are cummulated in range <0.9,1>. In publications I've found the treshold value as ~0.4 which is almost impossible to find on my images.

I calculated NDSI also for DN values and everything seems to be fine - range of NDSI values is <-1,1>, treshold ~0.4. But I would like to apply TOA correction because in next stage I'll compare NDSI images from different acquistition time.

I've tried different software to do the analysis: PCI Geomatica, ArcMap, RStudio... Results are the same...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use [surface reflectance](http://landsat.usgs.gov/CDR_LSR.php) Landsat scenes. TOA reflectance of green layer has strong atmospheric interference, so you need to work with a corrected image (images are free, only submit an orden in [EarthExplorer](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov))

Take in account that some pixels will be out of range or `NA`, it depends of DOY, zone and image's quality (derived from cloud cover).

```
library(raster)
library(RStoolbox)
library(rasterVis)

test <- stackMeta("/path/to/LC82330822016159LGN00.xml") # path/row 233/82

NDSI <- function(green, swir1){
  (green-swir1)/(green+swir1)
}

NDSI.result <- overlay(test[[3]],test[[6]], fun = NDSI)

levelplot(NDSI.result)
```

[image: ndsi]

Also, the cumulative distribution is the same one than yours:

```
histogram(NDSI.result)
```

[image]

Comment: great example! Wht not use a built-in dataset to make your example reproiducible though? mtlFile  <- system.file("external/landsat/LT52240631988227CUB02_MTL.txt", package="RStoolbox"); test <- stackMeta(mtlFile)

Comment: I have two reasons. First, surface reflectance product comes with two metadata files, classic `MTL.txt` and `.xml file`. MTL doesn't work as easy as you show with `stackMeta()`, because it has L1 data information. `.xml` file comes with atmospheric corrected parameters, like scale factor or QA bit flags. Second, build-in dataset have no snow, so, it isn't a good example for NDSI.

Comment: Fair point, my bad for the comment!